# Python List caused out of memory?

Tags: python

I have a text file about 12GB, with a total of 150 million lines. When I traverse each line in the text, I use the split function to split each line in python. The result shows that the program terminates because the memory is full after reading 40 million lines. When I delete the following two lines, it can run normally without memory error.

```
        data_seq_arr.append(seq_arr)
        data_tag_arr.append(tag_arr)
```

it seems the size of list data_seq_arr is too large that caused out of memory, How should I modify the program? the problem code is as follows:

```
data_seq_arr=[]
data_tag_arr=[]
f1=open("150_million.txt")
for line in f1:
    #each line format:x1 x2 x3...xn@@@y1 y2 y3...yn
    line_arr=line.split("@@@")
    if len(line_arr) == 2:
        seq,tag=line_arr[0],line_arr[1]
        if " " in seq and " " in tag:
            seq_arr = seq.split(" ")
            tag_arr = tag.split(" ")
            data_seq_arr.append(seq_arr)
            data_tag_arr.append(tag_arr)
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with `data_seq_arr` and `data_tag_arr`?

Comment: You don't have enough memory available to do that. It really is that simple. However, @Tomalak asks a pertinent question. You have to ask yourself if/why you really need all that data in memory. You should consider using [temporary] files for the contents of *data_seq_arr* and *data_tag_arr*

Comment: Millions of strings can't fit in the RAM. Try not saving as lists and use the strings immediately, if possible.

Comment: @user9799714 What do intend to do with the 2 huge lists?

Comment: @WalidSiddik says "Millions of strings can't fit in the RAM". That may be strictly true but you need to bear in mind that memory is virtual - i.e., it's a combination of actual RAM and swap space. Therefore, the limit is not constrained by RAM size but of RAM and swap space. Bear in mind though that if large amounts of swap are being used, your program is likely not to perform well.